# DataSource cannot be resolved - Weka

Tags: java, weka

I have the following class to perform PCA on a arff file. I have added the Weka jar to my project but I am still getting an error saying `DataSource cannot be resolved` and I don't know what to do to resolve it. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong?

```
package project;

import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader;
import weka.gui.visualize.Plot2D;
import weka.gui.visualize.PlotData2D;
import weka.gui.visualize.VisualizePanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.math.plot.FrameView;
import org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel;
import org.math.plot.PlotPanel;
import org.math.plot.plots.ScatterPlot;

import weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents;
import weka.attributeSelection.Ranker;

public class PCA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Load the Data.
            DataSource source = new DataSource("../data/ingredients.arff");
            Instances data = source.getDataSet();

            // Perform PCA.
            PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents();
            pca.setVarianceCovered(1.0);
            //pca.setCenterData(true);
            pca.setNormalize(true);
            pca.setTransformBackToOriginal(false);
            pca.buildEvaluator(data);

            // Show transform data into eigenvector basis.
            Instances transformedData = pca.transformedData();
            System.out.println(transformedData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you load this arff file into Weka using the gui interface? If not, there's a problem with your file. If so, there's a problem with your code.